# How to flatten a numpy array of dtype object

Tags: python, numpy

I'm taking ndarray slices with different length and I want my result to be flat.
For example:

```
a = np.array(((np.array((1,2)), np.array((1,2,3))), (np.array((1,2)), np.array((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)))))
```

Is there any straight way to make this array flat by using numpy functionalities (without loop)?

Comment: In this example, what do you expect the result to be?

Comment: Using a NumPy array of dtype `object` doesn't help to speed things up.  They are similar to Python lists, and they are only useful if you need something exposing the same interface as a NumPy array.  What is your aim with using this weird data structure?

Comment: I have tags for my signal in random intervals. Slicing returns me this type (since when slices have different lengths).

Answer (score 25):

You could try **flattening** it and then using **hstack**, which stacks the array in sequence horizontally.

```
>>> a = np.array(((np.array((1,2)), np.array((1,2,3))), (np.array((1,2)), np.array((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)))))
>>> np.hstack(a.flatten())
array([1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```