# Expanding image field in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, image, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas Dataframe that contains the following fields:

```
ID TYPE_01 TYPE_02 SPRITE
1  12      8       [Image]
2  11      9       [Image]
3  9       nan     [Image]
4  3       12      [Image]
5  8       nan     [Image]
```

TYPE_01 and TYPE_02 are classifications over the image, that I'll try to classify using machine learning methods (I am using sklearn). SPRITE contains a 64x64 HSV images that I'll feed to the training method.

I am trying to flatten the images in one big 2D matrix of dimensions (#Records,64*64*3) for use in a PCA Decomposition, but I am having some problems. I managed to do it using for loops over each record, but I think this may be a little inefficient (I allocated a new array, and assigned record by record the flattened image).

Is there a better way to do this using Pandas/Numpy? If a get the shape of the dataframe using `df.values.shape` I get a `(#Records,4)`, so a simple flatten, ravel or reshape over the whole dataframe didnt help me.

I looked at some similar questions line [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942794/how-to-flatten-a-numpy-array-of-dtype-object), but they didnt apply to this case.

Comment: Are the sprites 3d numpy arrays?

Comment: Yes. They are (64 x 64 x 3), and have the same dimension over all records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply numpy's reshape to the entire column of Sprites to flatten them.  (I created random data fro my Sprites)

```
df.SPRITE.apply(lambda x: np.reshape(x, -1))

Out[1]:
0    [202, 82, 70, 34, 134, 54, 231, 244, 107, 179,...
1    [66, 14, 120, 18, 26, 57, 59, 2, 58, 109, 223,...
2    [47, 227, 1, 102, 51, 110, 83, 220, 101, 161, ...
Name: SPRITE, dtype: object
```

If you want it all as a single numpy array, you can pass the above output to `vstack`

```
np.vstack(df.SPRITE.apply(lambda x: np.reshape(x, -1)))

Out[2]:
array([[202,  82,  70, ..., 145, 226,  97],
       [ 66,  14, 120, ...,  42,  64,  48],
       [ 47, 227,   1, ...,  87, 102, 156]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
np.vstack([i.reshape(1, -1) for i in df.SPRITE.values.tolist()])
```

Unverified code as I am on phone